# How to query parameters correctly in JS?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I'm trying to query parameters `localhost:8888?title=associate&name=John` and I have written the code below, but editor shows errors in `if-else` statement. Is the whole concept incorrect? The idea is that if there's no parameters, it would use the default values "who" and "department".

```
const handleRequest = (request) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const params = url.searchParams;
  let who = "employee";
  let department = "admin";
       
  if (params.has("title") || params.has("name")) {
    return new Response(`Please address your request to ${params.get("title")} called ${params.get("name")}.`);     
  } else {
    return new Response(`Please address your request to ${who} in the ${department}.`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Not `OR` in your if statement. Replace it with `||`, which means "or".

Comment: [`OR` should be `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: Yes, just corrected it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Still wondering why the code doesn't return just one parameter. If query is just ?title=trainee, it doesn't use the default for "name", but gives null instead. Having four different if-else statements doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

`URLSearchParams` object provides lots of methods (like `get(param), has(param)`) to access the query string parameters.

```js
const url = new URL(
  'http://example.com/path/index.html?message=hello&who=world'
);
url.searchParams.get('message'); // => 'hello'
url.searchParams.get('missing'); // => null
//So you can simply use
let messageParam = url.searchParams.get("message") || "default value";
```

You can read more about it here

https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/#31-parsing-query-string

---